# How to accomplish this binding

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datacontext

I have the following scenarion. I have an Object, lets call it X that needs to be set as the datacontext of a combobox.

Object X consists of three objects.

- propA - object => ID, PropB_ID
- propB - collection of objects => ID, propC_ID
- propC - Collection of objects => ID, Text

they are related  to each other.

- propA:propB -> n:1
- propB:propC -> n:1

All of the IDs are set and valid, but they do not have references between eachother. There is no integrity between them.

So I need to have the combobox items represent the collection propB, show the "Text" propery from propC and the selected item (propB) set into "SelectedID" in propA

I have no Idea how to acompluish this. If they would have references between eachother it would be no problem, but since they do not, I do not what to do.

Comment: have you looked on google or even this site for key word `how to bind combobox` for example

Comment: i took me to long to decipher your class hierarchy. But i think what you need is a Converter, so you bind the id, create a converter and inside that converter you query the given id to find the actual object. Other idea, create a proxy object that already evaluates your cross references. This is usually the job of a View model.

Comment: I know how to bind the combobox. It's not a neewbie question. The problem is much harder thaen it looks. The objects do not have references between them. There is a semantical connection, but not a direct reference. So I can not bind it directly and set the datatemplate as I would like to.

Comment: @ dowhilefor this is exactly what I thought might help